# Deploying a Node.js React App, on CPanel - 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web-applications, cpanel, web-deployment

I uploaded my build folder to the CPanel public_html folder but when I go to the domain 'https://domain-name/build/' I am just getting a blank page. When I look at the page source there is a 'Failed to load resource error: the server responded with a status of 404 ()' for the static js and css files. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you run this static build in your local environment? Just try Chrome web server and see if you have the same error.

Comment: I am not saying to run 'npm start' because it is not using your static build with this command via a node server. You need to look at your build configurations and make sure the error is not from there.

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app` ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are serving your app from a subdirectory, which is `/build`. To make it work, you have to let the the frontend builder know that you are serving your app within the subdirectory. Do the following to make it work,
I assume you are using `create-react-app`,

1. First, add a `basename` property to your route,

   ```
   <Router basename={'/build'}>
     {/* your Route config */}
   </Router>
   ```
2. update the `homepage` property to the `package.json` file,

   ```
   "homepage": "https://yourdomain/build",
   ```
3. Also update the Routes

   ```
   <Router basename={'/build'}>
     <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`} component={Home} />
   </Router>
   ```

   `process.env.PUBLIC_URI` variable will be replace by `homepage` in the build time.
4. change all the occurrence `to` attribute in your react `Link` component

   ```
   <Link to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/page`}> ... </Link>
   ```

Now, your application should work under `https://yourdomain/build`.

Comment: Yup, I am using create-react-app. I will try that out right now, thank you for your help!